# Why a date assignments in a dataframe is not a date type?

Tags: python, pandas, date

The `df_vol` DataFrame is created as follows

```
df_vol = df.loc[:, 1].map(fd.retrieve_symbol_datetime).to_frame('maturity')
df_vol['date'] = df_vol.index.date

df_vol.head()
                           maturity        date
2018-11-01 11:31:53.023  2022-04-01  2018-11-01
2018-11-01 16:30:15.287  2022-04-01  2018-11-01
2018-11-01 10:23:06.779  2022-10-01  2018-11-01
2018-11-01 16:30:15.291  2022-10-01  2018-11-01
2018-11-01 11:30:56.251  2018-12-01  2018-11-01
```

A further inspection of `df_vol` shows

```
df_vol.dtypes
maturity    category
date          object
dtype: object
```

I would expect that `maturity` column is of a date type as it is filled by the content of the `fd.retrieve_symbol_datetime()`, a function that returns `pandas.datetime()`.
Also, the `date` column is an object type though it takes the values from `index.date`.

I'm interested in having types of `datetime` since I eventually I want to do the difference

```
pd.eval("(df_vol.maturity - df_vol.date)")
```

**retrieve_symbol_datetime()**

```
def retrieve_symbol_datetime(future: str):
    """
    Retrieves the maturity date of a future whose format is of the form AAAMYY.

    Params
    -------
    future : string, of form 'AAAMYY'
        This format is for futures where 'AAA' is the string that identifies
        the symbol, 'M' is the character that identifies the month, and 'YY' is
        a two-digit number that identifies the year.

    Returns : pandas.datetime
        Returns the date of maturiry of the future's symbol.

    Example
    -------
    If future = 'DI1Z20', then it returnts a pandas.datetime(2020, 12, 01).

    """
    year = 2000 + int(future[4: 6])
    month = convert_letter_symbol_month(future[3: 4])
    return pd.datetime(year, month, 1).date()
```

Comment: It would be helpful to know what package "fd" corresponds to. Please include the relevant import statements. It also appears that you are doing df.head() which is displaying the contents of the dataframe df, but you are calculating the dataframe df_vol. Did you want to do df_vol.head() instead?

Answer (score 1):

There is problem `categorical` column, one possible solution is decategorical it and for `date` use [`floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.floor.html) for remove times:

```
df_vol['maturity'] = pd.to_datetime(df_vol['maturity'].astype(str))
df_vol['date'] = df_vol.index.floor('d')

df_vol['diff'] = (df_vol['maturity'] - df_vol['date']).dt.days
print (df_vol)
                          maturity       date  diff
2018-11-01 11:31:53.023 2022-04-01 2018-11-01  1247
2018-11-01 16:30:15.287 2022-04-01 2018-11-01  1247
2018-11-01 10:23:06.779 2022-10-01 2018-11-01  1430
2018-11-01 16:30:15.291 2022-10-01 2018-11-01  1430
2018-11-01 11:30:56.251 2018-12-01 2018-11-01    30
```